# Elastic search configuration issue with client call php

Tags: php, search, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch API php to build search results. I have configured everything in my xampp server. All the libraries downloaded from composer.json. In my composer.json file contains below code

```
  {
    "require": {
        "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "~2.0"
    }
}
```

Libraries are successfully downloaded. After that i initialize the elastic search with below code

```
 <?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 
    $client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
```

It shows fatal error like as follows

```
Fatal error: Class 'ClientBuilder' not found in E:\Xampp\htdocs\codeporn\elasticsearch\app\init.php on line 4
```

So i change the config code as,

```
 require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';    
     $es = new Elasticsearch\Client([
        'hosts' => ['127.0.0.1:9200']]
    ]);
```

This also shows error like

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']' in E:\Xampp\htdocs\codeporn\elasticsearch\app\init.php on line 10
```

I am following the below youtube tutorial to build the search 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xb1dHLg-Lk

Please suggest what i went wrong in Elasticsearch - PHP. 
My PHP Version is 5.5.9

Comment: This is a syntax error as stated by the response: `'hosts' => ['127.0.0.1:9200']]` Remove the last bracket

Answer (score 8):

i have initialize the clientbuilder class, now it works fine

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

$client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
```

Answer (score 1):

you need install it with composer

```
composer require elasticsearch/elasticsearch
```